# List of figures and tables not appearing

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I have citations present in the figures and tables and after reading through the forum I changed the code to the following to make the references appear in order.

```
\caption[]{caption. \cite{ref}}
```

But now I have the issue that my list of figures and tables are not showing up. The content is empty. Do you guys know, how to fix this?
The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows to import images
\usepackage{float} % Allows to control float positions
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,skip=10pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myequation}{
\begin{align}
\scalebox{1.5}{$\BODY$}
\end{align}
}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
%\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
\usepackage[
  separate-uncertainty = true,
  multi-part-units = repeat
]{siunitx}


% Blattlayout
\textwidth15cm

%Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}


\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}


\begin{document}

...


\newpage
\bibliography{database}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** example (including some references via filecontents) and raising the problem.

Comment: Does "[no text]" literally mean no text and you used an empty set of []? I'd so, place the caption tex tyou want to seem in the table of contents there as well but do not copy the cite command there.

Comment: Yes, when I say no text it is empty. If I remove that, the order of references get messed up, i.e., the reference used in the first figures shows up first whereas there are other references made before.

Comment: The [] means send nothing to the TOC, LOF or LOT,  Use `\caption{caption. \protect\cite{ref}}` instead.  Or `\caption[caption. \string\cite{ref}]{caption. \cite{ref}}`.